# Rails saving nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I got three models called `User`, `Account` and `AccountPermission`.

I established associations between `User` and `Account` through `AccountPermission` so, It's `has_many :through`

I also established `User` and `Account` with `has_many` via **creator_id**. Because, I need to know the creator of accounts.

Here is my associations,

[image: associations]

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

     has_many :created, class_name: 'Account', :foreign_key => 'creator_id'

     has_many :account_permissions, :class_name => 'AccountPermission'
     has_many :accounts, through: :account_permissions

     accepts_nested_attributes_for :account_permissions
```

**account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'

    has_many :accounts_permissions, :class_name => 'AccountPermission'
    has_many :users, through: :accounts_permissions
```

**account_permission.rb**

```
class AccountPermission < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :account

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
```

**controller#new**

```
 def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.account_permissions.build.build_account
    respond_with(@user)
 end
```

I'm creating `Account` and `User` same time with nested attributes. However, I also want to add a **creator_id** to my `User` in same transaction.

I'm currently adding creator_id to my user like this;,

`resource.accounts.last.update(creator_id: resource.id)`

It's a really low level solution and i'm not feeling well with it. Because, I'm sending an extra update query every single time.

Question is, is there any way to handle this in account creation?

**UPDATED**

```
def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource.persisted?

      # TODO: 
      resource.accounts.last.update(creator_id: resource.id)

      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message! :notice, :signed_up
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message! :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}"
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      set_minimum_password_length
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use callback after_create in model Account ?

```
class Account 

after_create :give_creator_id

  def give_creator_id
    creator_id = accounts_permissions.first.user_id
  end

end
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to add it during first transaction that creating account and user.

Comment: share you method `create` from contoller if you can